# Check if the selected link match in multiple given links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have the following playlist rows , these rows already exist in playlist

```
<div class="total-row">
    <div class="total-title" src="music/04_LCR_Mae_Terra.mp3">04_LCR_Mae_Terra</div>
</div>
<div class="total-row">
    <div class="total-title" src="music/06LCR_Homem_Mal.mp3">06LCR_Homem_Mal</div>
</div>
<div class="total-row">
    <div class="total-title" src="music/06LCR_Homem_Mal.mp3">06LCR_Homem_Mal</div>
</div>
```

and also i have the links to add the song in playlist

```
<div id="playlinks">
    <li mp3="music/04_LCR_Mae_Terra.mp3" class="add_link"></li>
    <li mp3="music/05_LCR_Jack_Matador.mp3" class="add_link"></li>
</div>
```

so i will match the selected (clicked) link's mp3 link with already exists links in playlist (i will match with all rows), if that already exist then it does not add and if not exist then add the selected one. i am using the following jquery code

```
if i use the below code

$(document).on("click", ".add_link", function(){

    var mp3 = $(this).attr("mp3");
    var foundInPlaylist =
      $(".total-row .total-title[src$='"+ ('/'+mp3) +"']").length;
     if(foundInPlaylist){
        alert("found");
     } else{
       alert("not found");
     }
});
```

this does not work, even if i just write alert(foundInPlaylist ); it alerts "0";

```
if i use the second solution

$(".add_link").click(function () {
var newMp3 = $(this).attr("mp3");
var exists = false;
$(".total-row").each(function(){
    var oldmp3 = $(this).children(".total-title").attr("src");
    if(oldmp3.indexOf(newMp3) > 0 )
    {
        exists = true
    }
});
if(exists)
{
    alert("song already exists");
}
else {
        alert("song does not exist");
    }
});
```

it also does not work for me

Thanks

Comment: Hi, they seem to work for me, directly copied from your code above (MacSafari 5.1.9 + MacFirefox 23.0.1): http://jsfiddle.net/KRnWR/3/ http://jsfiddle.net/KRnWR/4/

Comment: ye @biziclop now worked for me, i changed your this statement
('/'+mp3)
 to 
(mp3)
and this worked, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could try using the jQuery "attribute ends with" selector `$("[attribute$='value']")`:

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/

Quick example in fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KRnWR/2/

```
// http://api.jquery.com/on/
$(document).on("click", ".add_link", function(){

    var mp3 = $(this).attr("mp3");

    // http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/
    var foundInPlaylist =
      $(".total-row .total-title[src$='"+ ('/'+mp3) +"']").length;

    // for (brain)killing programmers :)
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else
    if( foundInPlaylist ){
      alert( mp3 + ' found in playlist.');
    }else{
      alert( mp3 + ' not found in playlist.');
    }
});
```

I prepend the `'/'` before the filename of the mp3 to prevent false matches like these:

```
          mp3="lala.mp3">
src="music/lalalala.mp3">
```

Comment: Thanks but i want that operate on click event, and check all the links and alert only once, means when i click on one of the given links then it check all the rows if that src exist in one of them then alert only once that this src is already exist

Comment: Hi, I updated my answer to be more clicky, and I changed `click()` to `on()` just because. :) BTW, my solution might fail with filenames having funny characters, for example quotes.

Comment: thanks biziclop can you please simplify the alert statement means you write in (if, else) statements, because i need to write a big code if that does not exist in playlist

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code:

```
$(".add_link").click(function () {
var newMp3 = $(this).attr("mp3");
var exists = false;
$(".total-row").each(function(){
    var oldmp3 = $(this).children(".total-title").attr("src");
    if(oldmp3.indexOf(newMp3) > -1 )
    {
        exists = true
    }


});
if(exists)
{
    alert("song already exists");
}
else {
        alert("song does not exist");
    }
});
```

here is working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/YW46k/

Comment: Ive made a mistake. Change line "oldmp3.indexOf(newMp3) > -1" (0 becomes -1) and it will work: http://jsfiddle.net/YW46k/1/